# Python code to calculate base Lagrange Polynomial is taking too long for large numbers of data

Tags: python, numpy, loops, interpolation, polynomials

So, I need help minimizing the time it takes to run the code with large numbers of data only by using NumPy. I think the for loops made my code inefficient.. But I do not know how to make the for loop into a list comprehension, which might help it run faster..

```
def lagrange(p,node,n,x):
    m=[]

        #base lagrange polynomial
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(p+1):
            L=1
            for k in range(p+1):
                if k!=j:
                    L= L*(x[i] - node[k])/(node[j] - node[k])
                
            m.append(L)
    lagrange= np.array(m).reshape(n,p+1)
    return lagrange


def interpolant(a,b,p,n,x,f):
        m=[]
        node=np.linspace(a,b,p+1)
        for j in range(n):
             polynomial=0 
            for i in range(p+1):
                polynomial += f(node[i]) * lagrange(p,node,n,x) 
        m.append(polynomial) 

        interpolant = np.array(inter) 

                return interpolant
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the value of `lagrange_poly(...)` is **recomputed `n*(p+1)` times for no reason** which is very very expensive! You can compute it once before the loop, store it in a variable and reuse the variable later.

Here is the fixed code:

```py
def uniform_poly_interpolation(a,b,p,n,x,f,produce_fig):
        inter=[]
        xhat=np.linspace(a,b,p+1)
        #use for loop to iterate interpolant.
        mat = lagrange_poly(p,xhat,n,x,1e-10)[0]
        for j in range(n):
                po=0 
                for i in range(p+1):
                    po += f(xhat[i]) * mat[i,j]
        inter.append(po) 

        interpolant = np.array(inter) 
        return interpolant
```

This should be much much faster.

---

Moreover, the execution is slow because **accessing scalar values of Numpy arrays from CPython is very slow**. Numpy is designed to work with array and not to extract scalar values in loops. Additionally, the loop CPython interpreter are relatively slow. You can solve this problem efficiently with **Numba** that compile your code to a very fast native code using a JIT-compiler.

Here is the Numba code:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def lagrange_poly(p, xhat, n, x, tol):
    error_flag = 0
    er = 1
    lagrange_matrix = np.empty((n, p+1), dtype=np.float64)

    for l in range(p):
        if abs(xhat[l] - xhat[l+1]) < tol:
            error_flag = er

    # Base lagrange polynomial
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(p+1):
            L = 1.0
            for k in range(p+1):
                if k!=j:
                    L = L * (x[i] - xhat[k]) / (xhat[j] - xhat[k])
            lagrange_matrix[i, j] = L

    return lagrange_matrix, error_flag
```

Overall, this should be *several order of magnitude faster*.

Comment: thankyou for commenting! but unfortunately, I'm not allowed to import anything else except for NumPy..

Comment: Ok. I just found another big issue in the code meanwhile. Storing the result of `lagrange_poly` should be much much faster for big `n` and `p`.

Comment: if possible could you change the variables and code to match the edited version?